# Is there a way to block your ISP from controlling the password of your main router?

Tags: network, router, internet

I got internet installed at my home earlier today by [Bright House Networks](http://www.brighthouse.com).

When I asked the installation technician about changing the router administration password, he said that he can change it to what I want while he is on the premises, or otherwise I can call them and they can change it remotely.

My concern is that if they are controlling the password, they can control the settings in the router as well (and some of these I prefer to control on my own). I understand that I can completely-mess-up-the-connection between my home and ISP but in the worst case I can always reset the router to the default values and, if needed, after that call the ISP. I do not think I need them controlling the password to the router.

So the question I wanted to ask is if there is a way to block the ISPs remote access to the router? (I have some ideas on how to do this myself but wanted to see what the community says)

Comment: You can furnish your own gateway device, but I've heard (unconfirmed) they require a backdoor even into those. I usually just put my own router behind theirs, just as if theirs was a "dummy modem" - they can control theirs all they want, but they won't be able to get into mine.

Comment: @Iszi has the best solution: either tell them to pack their router up and take it away (if thats possible) or find the setting in their router that lets you forward 100% of traffic to your router (usually called "DMZ host" or similar) and then use your router for all the settings (port forwards, etc) from that point on.

Comment: @JeffMeden Instead of using the "DMZ Host", ask the ISP about how to set up "bridge mode". That disables WiFi, disables all but one LAN port, and effectively makes the gateway device behave as if it was just a modem.

Comment: Bridge mode is the way to go. It leaves them in "full control" over their device and forces it to just act as a modem and pass all traffic straight through. This also gives you complete control over your actual edge device and allows you to ensure your ISP has no access to it while allowing everything to continue working.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Blocking ISP access to their own device is not a clever idea.

Instead just buy another router and connect between ISP's router and your computers. Then move all configuration related to your LAN to your router and configure ISP's router as bridge (or put your own router in DMZ).

This way ISP will have access only to the bridge, and not to your LAN.

Comment: I would go one step further and purchase your own Modem & Router.

Answer (score 1):

It's not recommended, but it's possible. Look for an option labeled TR-069 in your router, then disable it. Simple as that. TR-069 basically enables your ISP to change every* setting in your router, and disabling it disables ISP control over your router.

But do take note that if your ISP has some configuration changes (very unlikely), It won't get to your router. In that case, when it fails to connect, turn it on again until internet connectivity is restored. Or do a factory reset.

Answer (score -1):

I mean your answer here really determines on the model/device they gave you.

Assuming typical name brand router/gateway device...

why not just do this:

1) get the ISP or service repair tech they send out to change the password for you to something you both know.

2) Then, after they leave log into the router/gateway device.

3) And change the password to something just you know.

4) Save settings.

You may have to google the common administration interface address for your particular model/device. But it's a pretty simple thing to do. Assuming your ISP isn't running a custom locked down firmware on the particular router/gateway they gave you.

Your last option is just return the router/gateway they are leasing to you, and save some money by buying your own router/gateway device.

Comment: Changing the password is no good here. I've had ISPs remotely change router settings while I was on a support call, *despite me having changed the password and explicitly objecting to the changes while on the call*. They have a habit of pushing firmware updates and forcing reboots at-will with zero notice, too.

Comment: I never heard of so invasive ISP? What country you live? I would change my ISP...if they do this, they can be doing worse things

Comment: I can definitely see this happening in the U.S. I've had similar experiences. The people on the phone just have buttons to push. They don't actually know what they're doing, until you get to the higher levels of support, and by then they've already pushed all those buttons, because they're not allowed to elevate until they do.